# Why doesn't ssh always ask me to verify the server's key fingerprint?

Tags: ssh, openssh

Sometimes, when I connect over SSH to a server that is not in my known hosts file, ssh gives me the message:

> The authenticity of host '[domain] ([ip_address])' can't be established.
>   RSA key fingerprint is [fingerprint].
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

If I select 'yes', then I get the message:

> Warning: Permanently added '[domain]' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

But for some other servers, (e.g. github.com) I am not prompted to continue, and instead I *immediately* get the following message, which is phrased slightly differently:

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '[ip_address]' to the list of known hosts.

What causes this difference in behaviour? And more importantly, when I am *not* prompted, do I need to manually check the key that has been added to the known_hosts file before continuing to work with the server?

In both cases I am authenticating via public-key. I'm running OS X 10.10.3, using the system-installed OpenSSH.

Comment: yes, that's life!

Comment: I'm guessing it is because large sites like github use multiple servers which share a domain, but have differant host keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I'm just an idiot.

Whilst, [as Jakuje states](https://superuser.com/a/950519/36098), SSHFP does allow sites to store their public key fingerprint in their DNS records, in this instance the key *was* already in the known-hosts file, under the domain name, (which I discovered by adding the `-v` debug flag to my `ssh` command).

As the informational message I received explains, a new line was being added to the file *for the IP address being used*.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably caused by the fact that these sited have their ssh fingerprint stored in DNS so they do not bother users with verifying the keyse anymore.

The feature is called SSHFP record. You can verify this using `ssh-keygen -r github.com`

Comment: Thanks! It looks as though `dig SSHFP github.com` is the command you need for querying the DNS records, though. The command you quote is I think for *generating* such records.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning the `VerifyHostKeyDNS` ssh config setting, which needs to be set correctly for the DNS to be queried for SSHFP. This seemed to be switched off by default in my configuration.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this @Rich. I have this option also disabled by default. Anyway my and your command does both lookup. Storing is more complicated